# Network Incident Report Template

Tags: networking, templates

I'm looking for a network incident report template.

Is there any template that you use in your company?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of what goes into an incident report depends on your audience; the report you file with the technical teams may differ from the report for customers.  Here are some sections I use for an internal report.

- Report title
- Report author(s) and contact info
- Report date
- Report summary/brief synopsis
- Incident severity (if you have a severity level scheme)
- Incident duration
- Services impacted
- Users/customers impacted
- Impact to service level agreement(s)
- Incident timeline (including detection and notifications)
- Incident details: root cause and analysis
- Conclusion: description how the incident will be kept from happening again

  - Short term/temporary fix(es)
  - Long term/permanent fix(es)
- For internal reports: Action items by team/assignee with applicable tracking/bug numbers
- For internal reports: Related incident/ticket numbers
- For internal reports: Log excerpts or links to archived logs

I'm keen to see what other people track in their reports!

Comment: I'd change conclusion to two items: Temporary fix and Permanent fix, but otherwide +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

- Critical incident report

  Header - network information, system information, and severity info 1-5.

  5 is system outage.
- Observer

  Person who observed the incident
- Summary

  What was observed.
- Background

  Has this happened before? Why was this found at this time.
- Issues

  What this impacts and why?
- Recommended fixes

  How do I fix this?
- Audit points

  How do I check to see if this is fixed?